# What is outData.writeInt() does in Java?

Tags: java, function, mouseevent

I am new to Java programming language, infact I only have some basic concept of programming. I came across the following piece of Java code and I couldn't understand a function in there. I would be grateful if someone kindly explain it to me what does 'outData.writeInt()' do and how to use it? Thank you.

```
 try {
    if(moe.getSource() == forward)outData.writeInt(1);
    if(moe.getSource() == reverse)outData.writeInt(2);
    if(moe.getSource() == leftTurn)outData.writeInt(3);
    if(moe.getSource() == rightTurn)outData.writeInt(4);
    if(moe.getSource() == speedUp)outData.writeInt(6);
    if(moe.getSource() == slowDown)outData.writeInt(7);

    outData.flush(); 
    }
 catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("\nIO Exception writeInt");
 }
```

Comment: What class is outData an instance of?

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google gives me the doc for [DataOutputStream.writeInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt%28int%29)

> Writes an int to the underlying output stream as four bytes, high byte
>   first. If no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented
>   by 4

Your `DataOutputStream` will be writing to a file, or perhaps a network connection.

Comment: While I agree, this sounds more like a comment. ;)

Comment: @brian-agnew thank you for your quick response. Actually above code is the part of a program that is written in Java and the program is able to communicate with NXT Lego as well as allows to control it's movement by clicking on forward/reverse/left/right buttons. Here, what i actually wanna know is how does it work and is there any alternative to this?

Answer (score 2):

[writeInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt%28int%29) is documented in DataOutputStream

> Writes an int to the underlying output stream as four bytes, high byte first. If no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented by 4.

In simple terms it writes a 32-bit `int` value in big-endian.

---

If you want to know what a method does, it good to start with the source

```
/**
 * Writes an <code>int</code> to the underlying output stream as four
 * bytes, high byte first. If no exception is thrown, the counter
 * <code>written</code> is incremented by <code>4</code>.
 *
 * @param      v   an <code>int</code> to be written.
 * @exception  IOException  if an I/O error occurs.
 * @see        java.io.FilterOutputStream#out
 */
public final void writeInt(int v) throws IOException {
    out.write((v >>> 24) & 0xFF);
    out.write((v >>> 16) & 0xFF);
    out.write((v >>>  8) & 0xFF);
    out.write((v >>>  0) & 0xFF);
    incCount(4);
}
```

Comment: is there any alternative way than this? can we replace outData.writeint with other function.

Comment: yes, can write each byte a time or as two 16-bit values if you prefer.

Comment: ok... but I want to know actually what does it do??? I want to know after passing the integer what will happen...

Comment: I don't know what you don't know. Can you say specifically what you want to know?

Comment: I want to know what will happen if integer 1,2,3,4,6,7 is changed??? What is the main job of this integer...